# PrimeNG ConfirmDialog not popping up after version change

Tags: angular, primeng, confirm-dialog

Confirm Dialog is not centered after version change to 9.1.3.

If I place `confirmDialog` tag on top of the HTML page, it displays at the top and move other components. If I place it at the bottom of the HTML page then it displays at the bottom of the screen.
Instead of popping up it just displays based on the tag position.

HTML code:

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"></p-confirmDialog>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
        accept: () => {
          ---
          --
        },
        reject: () => {
          //alert('do not navigate to next screen');
        }
      });
```